# I am musical in function

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, poetry

> My prefix can fool you
>   Even though it’s not a pro
>   My infix is a pipe
>   Through which fluids flow
>
> My postfix: a conjunction
>   But more of a disjunction
>   I have no intersection
>   I am musical in function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are a

> Conductor

My prefix can fool you
Even though it’s not a pro

> **Con** = both a deceptive person and the opposite of "pro"

My infix is a pipe
Through which fluids flow

> **Duct** = a tube or passageway through which liquids flow

My postfix: a conjunction
But more of a disjunction

> **Or** = a conjuction in English but also a logical disjunction.

I have no intersection
I am musical in function

> **Conductor** = The leader of an orchestra.
>  Also the word Conductor is broken up into Con + duct + or here (no intersection between affixes).